# Javascript: how to document.print option value in Select block?

Tags: javascript, select

The below returns `[object HTMLOptionElement]` while I try to return the value.

```
  document.write(document.getElementById("allSelect").options[0]).value;
```

by value, I mean the thing called `value` there (there is a form around it but not relevant now):

```
<select name="allSelect" id="allSelect" size=3>
<option value="1"selected">1</option>  
<option value="2">2</option>  
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

How can I return the value of an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `.value` after the `)` instead of before.

```
document.write(document.getElementById("allSelect").options[0].value);
```

Happens to the best of us.